# Show database content in right side

Tags: php

i have a problem, i want to show 'navn' in the left side of the page, and 'average' in the right
but i dont know how? :

```
(echo $i . ". " . $info['Navn']." ". number_format((float)$info['Average'], 1). 
"<br/><hr>";
```

i've tried the code below, and it shows the navn in the left, and the average in the right as its supose to, but average is just 2 lines below navn, it want it to bee in the same line?

```
echo $i . ". " . $info['Navn']."<p align='right'>". number_format((float)$info['Average'], 1).
 "<br/><hr>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using span instead of p and style="float: right;" instead of align = "right"

```
echo $i . ". " . $info['Navn']."<span style='float: right;'>".number_format((float)$info['Average'], 1). "</span><br/><hr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use css?

```
<p style=" text-align: right ">
```

you can probably also

```
<p style=" display: block; clear: right; float:right ">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
 <div style='float: left;'>left text</div>
 <div style='float: right;'>right text</div>
</div>
```